# Paging and Sorting in Asp.net Repeater Control

Tags: asp.net, xml, repeater

In following code i am trying to show the latest record on the top of repeater. I also want to include paging in repeater.Paging is done successful in page but i am having trouble when i do sorting in repeater.So my question is this that how can i do sorting and paging in repeater?

My code:

```
private void Get_Data()
    {

        String File = Server.MapPath("~/Data/BlogContent.xml");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds.ReadXml(File);

        DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
        dv.Sort = "id DESC";
        DataTable dt = dv.Table;
        ViewState.Add("Mytable", dt);

    }
    private void Bind_Data(int take, int pageSize)
    {
        PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource();
        page.AllowCustomPaging = true;
        page.AllowPaging = true;
        DataTable dtv = (DataTable)ViewState["Mytable"];
        DataView dv = new DataView();
        dv = dtv.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "id ASC";
        dv.RowFilter = "id>=" + pageSize + " AND " + "id<=" + take;
        page.DataSource = dv;
        page.PageSize = psize;
        Repeater1.DataSource = page;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int rowcount = dtv.Rows.Count;
            CreatePagingControl(rowcount);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For paging Check this.Here is full example of paging.link

[paging and sorting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37864/Repeater-with-Paging-and-Sorting-Features)

Comment: sorry but i did not find any link

Comment: your link is good but first i need sorting in repeater.. please tell me if you have any link for sorting in repeater

Comment: have u checked code project link. if not then check this. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37864/Repeater-with-Paging-and-Sorting-Features

Answer (score 0):

** Read the article:
Custom paging in Repeater control in asp.net(C#, VB)** 
http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/05/custom-paging-in-repeater-control-in.html

Comment: i am using xml here and in your article you are using sql database i did it with sql its work but my requirement is with xml